# Observation about twin primes: is it true? If so, why?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, recreational-mathematics, twin-primes

I noticed today that every set of twin primes except for $(3,5)$ and $(5,7)$ seems to have one of the two primes that can be represented by the sum of two squares. For example:
\begin{eqnarray*}
13=3^2+2^2 \\
17=4^2+1^2 \\
29=5^2+2^2
\end{eqnarray*}

... (sum of two squares works for all of these, I checked)
\begin{eqnarray*}
281&=&16^2+5^2 \\
313 &=&13^2+12^2 \\
349&=&18^2+5^2
\end{eqnarray*}

I am wondering if this works for all twin primes. If so, can someone explain why (because I have thought about it some but nothing really comes to mind)? Thank you.

Comment: primes are a sum of squares if they are not congruent to $3\bmod 4$, so for twin primes exactly one of them satisfies this condition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares

Comment: Please use Mathjax to typeset mathematical formulas.

Comment: $5=1^2+2^2$ so the pairs $(3,5)$ and $(5,7)$ are no exceptions.

Answer (score 6):

**HINT:** Consider the following theorem:

> An odd prime $p$ can be represented as a sum of $2$ squares if and only if it is congruent to $1$ modulo $4$.

Now notice that all odd primes must be congruent to either $1$ or $3$ modulo $4$, and if $p$ is congruent to $3$ mod $4$, then $p+2$ is congruent to $1$ mod $4$.

Your conjecture is true, and it follows from the above. Can you see why?

Answer (score 0):

You can generalize this result to the following:

Every prime pair $(p,p+k)$ which k is congruent to $2$ mod $4$ satisfies to your claim i.e.  one of two primes  $p$ , $p+k$ can be represented by the sum of two squares.